# Selecting all images from user which is clicked

Tags: php, laravel

I've started to learn Laravel version 5.4 recently but I have some error that I can't find a answer so far. I'm trying to make user-friendly urls and to load images of user by username not by ID.

So far I've made this in my controller

```
public function author(User $author) {

    $authorName = $author->username;

    $image = $author->with('author')->latestFirst()->paginate($this->limit);                          

    return view("author", compact('image', 'authorName'));

}
```

This in my route

```
Route::get('/author/{author}', [

    'uses' => 'HomeController@author',
    'as' => 'author'
]);
```

And this is my link

```
<a href="{{ route('author', $categoryImage->author->username ) }} ">{{ $categoryImage->author->username }}</a>
```

This is my Image model

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'image_author');
}
```

And User model

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

Whatever link I click I always get this error

> No query results for model [App\User].

I'm not even sure if my controller and routes are correct.

Comment: Because Laravel by default expects column `id` to be the identificator, while you expect column `username` to be the identificator. Basically, let's say you go to url /author/devk, behind the scenes Laravel will execute `User::where('id', '=', 'devk')->first()`. Obviously this won't return anything.

Comment: But why is this when I have function in my Model where I say which column `public function author()` or this doesn't matter?

Comment: Your `author()` function (in Image model) just defined a relationship. It tells laravel that `Image` model has a foreign key connected to model `User`. It's a convinient way to get "author" of the image. This has nothing to do with route model binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#implicit-binding

Put this in your user model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: Hm, actually this works. Thank you! if I understand correctly this `getRouteKeyName` is build-in function which takes parameter from route, right?

Comment: It tells routes which column to check (by default laravel expect routes like this: /author/{id}) for route model binding.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help :)